# ¿Por qué no funciona la propiedad [(value)] dentro de un mat select de Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

Tengo la siguiente tabla que se llena con la información que obtengo de un servicio, donde el campo ESTADO utiliza un mat select, y tiene la propiedad [(value)] para que por default tenga seleccionada la opcion que viene de mi servicio, pero no funciona, al cargar la pagina, no muestra por default el valor.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

                <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID. </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="cveEstado">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ESTADO </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                            <mat-select [(value)]="element.cveEstado" 
                                (selectionChange)="select($event.value,element)">
                                
                                <mat-option *ngFor="let estatus of estatusModel" [value]="estatus.cveEstado">
                                    {{estatus.descEstatus}}
                                </mat-option>
                            </mat-select>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="comentario">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> COMENTARIO </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.comentario}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="hora">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> HORA  </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                        <mat-form-field class="example-form-field">
                            <input matInput type="text" [value]="element.hora"
                                (keyup)="changeValueHora($event.target,element)">
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="botonSave">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> EDITAR </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
                        <button mat-fab (click)="guardar(element)">
                            <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </ng-container>

                <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
                <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
            </table>
```

Component.ts

```
  export class ControlComponent {

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'cveEstado', 'comentario', 'hora','botonSave'];
  controlModel: Control[] = [];
  contrEjec: Control = new Control();
  estatusModel: Estado[] = [];
  
  idSelecc: string = '';
  claveEstadoSelecc: any;
  horaInicioSelecc: string = '';
  

  constructor(private controlEjecService: ExecutionControlService, private dateAdapter: DateAdapter<Date>) {
    this.dateAdapter.setLocale('es-MX');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.obtenerControl();
    this.obtenerEstatus();
  }

  dataSource: any;
  private obtenerControl() {
    this.controlEjecService.obtenerControl().subscribe(response => {
      if (response.data.length == 0) {
        Swal.fire({
          icon: 'error',
          title: 'Error',
          text: 'Sin datos'
        });
      } else {
        this.controlModel = response.data;
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.controlModel);
      }

    });
  }

  private obtenerEstatus() {
    this.controlEjecService.obtenerEstatus().subscribe(resp => {
      this.estatusModel = resp.data;
    });
  }

  //obtiene el id del estatus seleccionado y la cve del estatus
  select(valor: Event, row: any) {
    this.idSelecc = row.id;
    this.claveEstadoSelecc = valor;
  }


  //obtiene el valor del iput hora y el id seleccionado
  changeValueHoraIn(e: any, row: any) {
    this.idSelecc = row.id;
    this.horaInicioSelecc = e.value;
  }

  guardar() {
    
  }


}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

qué debo de cambiar o cómo más puedo hacer para lograr que cuando cargue la pagina se muestre por default el valor en el option???

en app.module tengo importado lo siguiente:

```
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ComponentsModule, LoaderInterceptor } from 'cbmx-online';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { EnvironmentUrls } from './shared/interfaces';
import { ConfigurationService } from './shared/services/configuration/configuration.service';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';


function initializeAppFactory(configurationService: ConfigurationService): () => Promise<EnvironmentUrls> {
  return () => configurationService.loadConfig().toPromise();
}

/**
 * The main module of the application
 */
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ComponentsModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    FormsModule

  ],
  providers: [ConfigurationService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeAppFactory,
      multi: true,
      deps: [ConfigurationService]
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: LoaderInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Las versiones que ocupo son las siguiente:

Angular CLI: 10.2.4

Node: 16.19.1

Angular: 10.2.5

@angular/material   10.2.7

Answer (score 1):

Usar `[value]` en lugar `[(value)]` debería de funcionar.

***Recomendación***:

Crea un modulo para componentes de librerías, así tienes más organizado todo y evitas la carga de módulos innecesarios al iniciar la app.

Comment: Ya lo cambié así, pero siguen sin funcionar, no muestra nada :(

Comment: Asegúrate que `element.cveEstado` es un string (o lo que sea del tipo de valor que estes usando), agrega un `console.log` para ver que es lo que te regresa la petición Http. Porque si todos los demás funcionan y ese no, significa que el error viene de como usas los datos en el componente o en el servicio.

Comment: ya puse el console.log  en lo que me regresa el servicio y si muestra los estados, si trae datos

Comment: habrá alguna otra manera de forzarlo a que lo haga?

Comment: Si pero de que tipo?,  incluso en la documentación viene como `[(value)]`. El error no esta en el HTML.

Comment: modifiqué mi servicio y con eso quedó, gracias. , solo falta ver porque en el combo de Si y No, porque me pasa  lo mismo